# How to send a message with paragraph?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

How could "resposta" be sent as :

example1

example2

Instead of : example1 \n example2 ?

```
resposta = 'example1 \n example2'

     update.message.reply_text(
                '%s' %(resposta))
```

Comment: Use triple quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Aparently the `\n` works. I was just being stupid. For some reason when the code get the text containing `\n` from another file, its like the `\n` is ignored. But when the `\n` is declared inside the code itself, it works. So i just read the text from the another file and replace the old `\n` with new ones.